# How to replace all linebreaks from a datatable [PAD]

Tags: power-automate

I'd like to replace all linebreaks from my whole datatable, but I don't know how to do it...
I tried using 'Replace text' but I accomplished nothing.

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk1HO.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? Why do you need Power Automate? Are there several CSV files? 
I'm asking this because, if you just need to replace linebreaks in a file, you can use Notepad++ or another editor, it's quite straightforward.

Comment: If it’s PAD, could you not just open the CSV in Notepad and do a find and replace before consuming it into a data table?

Comment: @carlosherrera I'm using Power Automate to perform a web scraping, that data is gathered and later used for another web scraping, so I'd like to edit all elements in my data table without saving it anywhere at that point.

Comment: @Skin please see above

Comment: Oh, I see. You're using Power Automate Desktop, not the cloud version. From my understanding, you can't edit data tables on the fly. An option is to save all the data to a CSV file, and then open it up, replace the text, close it, and send it to the next scrapper.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decodeUriComponent('%0A')` in Replace formula to find "new line" character.

At the end the expression will look like this:

```
replace(outputs('Compose'),decodeUriComponent('%0A'),'-')
```

this will replace all "new-line" characters with dash "-".

Comment: I can't use it directely in my flow, which tool from that menu should I choose? I thought I can somehow do it in 'Replace text' + maybe some loops
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3zu.png

Comment: This is useful, however it will work only in Power Automate in the cloud.